# Can a <hr /> element have a closing tag?

Tags: html, xhtml

My colleague doesn't really know or understand html. Her job is to input information into the CMS and I've noticed she keeps closing her `<hr />` tags like this `<hr></hr>`.

I've had a Google but I can't find anywhere that says this isn't allowed or could cause problems. I know it's supposed to be `<hr />` but is it worth me telling her or is it unnecessary but valid markup?

NB The doctype for our website is 
`XHTML 1.0 Transitional` if that makes any difference.

**EDIT**

@Jeff had a good idea about validating. I used the following code and apparently this is valid  XHTML 1.0 Transitional

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr></hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried validating it? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: To be honest, the whole website is a mess and is far from validating. The `<hr></hr>` are the least of its worries.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

OK, `<hr></hr>` is actually a valid XHTML 1.0, too.

So, for XHTML 1.0:

- `<hr />` is valid
- `<hr></hr>` is valid
- `<hr>` is **not** valid

... for HTML 4.0:

- `<hr />` is valid
- `<hr></hr>` is **not** valid
- `<hr>` is valid

therefore the best option is to use `<hr />`, which is always valid.

Answer (score 10):

[HTML 4 says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.3):

> *Start tag:* **required**, *End tag:* **forbidden**

And as XHTML basically means that HTML tags need to have a closing tag, I would say `<hr />` is the only format you should consider.

As the others say, `<hr></hr>` is valid XHTML ([they even use it as example](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6)) but for compatibility reasons I would not use it.

Comment: The SGML-y answer is that `<hr/>` is equivalent to `<hr></hr>` -- there's the whole WWW extension to the SGML declaration that added the "NETENABL IMMEDNET" clause. The practical question is whether your target browser will understand you. Alas, that has nothing to do with SGML :-(

Comment: I would only ever use `<hr />` but since we are using an xhtml doctype and if I keep nitpicking at her html she might get really pissed off with me is it worth changing?

Comment: @MrMisterMan: I don't know. I would. Having empty elements with start and end tag just bloats up the size of the document (though it might not be that much).

Answer (score 3):

`<hr />` is merely shorthand for `<hr></hr>`; both are acceptable in XHTML documents. However, neither are acceptable in HTML documents, where `<hr>` should be used instead, which in turn is invalid in XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

No. `<hr />` should not have a closing tag.

It is invalid HTML.

It *is* valid XML and therefore technically it's valid xhtml, but you still shouldn't use it, even if you're using xhtml.

This is because all the browsers actually use their HTML parser even when rendering xhtml code, and therefore the a closing `</hr>` tag is seen as an error. Some browsers may even mis-interpret it as an additional `<hr>` element.

The only cross-browser compatible way of doing it is either `<hr>` (ie plain HTML) or `<hr />` if you want to have a valid xhtml document.

Comment: Unless sent as `application/xhtml+xml` as actual XML, in which case the browser does use an XML parser

Comment: @timw4mail - *some* browsers might, but not all. Especially older versions of IE.

Comment: IE doesn't have an XML parser that renders XHTML. It doesn't know what to do with it, so it tries to let you download it.

Comment: @tim4mail - my point exactly. Yes you can use `xhtml+xml` and it's great in theory, but in the real world you need to support IE, so you *have* to serve it as html, so that's what the browser will treat it as. Therefore, you can't use `<hr></hr>`.

Comment: Do you have a citation for suggesting that `</hr>` may be interpreted as `<hr>` in a browser? While its true that `</br>` can be treated as `<br>` (the html5 parser algorithm even requires it), I've never heard of a equivalent issue for `</hr>` or any other element.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no closing `hr` tag. The tag is purely self closing and the Doc Type Definition will reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an empty element, it makes no sense to have open and close tags.

However, XML requires all tags to be closed, hence the `<hr />` form.

I suppose in HTML, not XML, `<hr></hr>`is valid, but unnecessary.

Comment: Did you mean *I suppose in XML, not HTML* ?

Comment: Well, I guess it's probably valid either way, but it's also silly.

Comment: No, `<hr></hr>` is not valid in HTML 4, but should it be not valid in XML? XML elements consist of start and end tags of the form `<name></name>`.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is valid, most browsers will probably parse it "correctly" either way. In XML, I believe a `<script src="foo" />` is valid, though not in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The HR element draws a horizontal rule. This is a block element and does not require a closing tag.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb159725.aspx