# Why is my HR doing this

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why my HR tag is doing this do any of you know why

basically this is what it's doing
[image]

See the line top right next to logout, why is it there?

```
echo "<hr><h1>" . $row['blogTitle'] . "</hr></h1>";
```

CSS:

```
hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: your `<hr>` element should not have content inside of it. Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428184/can-a-hr-element-have-a-closing-tag

Comment: For starters, the `<hr>` tag is self-closing. There is no such thing as a start and end tag, `<hr></hr> = BAD`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Answer (score 1):

`<hr />` is a self-closing element with no children and it represents a horizontal rule. It's largely presentational and of limited use given that CSS allows any element to have borders.

Remove all mentions of `<hr>` and `</hr>` and instead use CSS to give your `<h1>` a `border:`  - be it `border-bottom` or `border-top`.

You can use `h1:first-child` to prevent the first `<h1>` from having a border if you only want borders to separate elements.